# Code tag/code highlight problem in sub-comment on askUbuntu mainpage

Tags: support, comments, formatting

I am wondering, why `code tag` and **bold text** option which both work perfectly fine in full comments doesn't work in sub-comments, like shown in the screenshot below, using the same syntax?!

Sometimes, when i write sub-comments, i almost use all of the 600 characters and things get a little messy for the receiver/person who reads it, because of the tight formatting, (no problem there) if it wasn't for the possibility to use both "code and bold tag option".

I have seen it is possible (at least for highlight code) [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line) (comment by **qbi**), even with a low reputation, but how. All variations tried failed so far!

[image: screenshotSub-comments]

Comment: `you mean like this?` \`you mean like this?\`

Comment: What do you mean by sub-comment? To me there are only comments.

Comment: `test` *test*  _test_ **test**  |||  Thank you Bruno, that answered my question!! [+1]up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Taken from [Comment Formating](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) from the Stack Overflow markdown guide*)

> Comments support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links are available.
>
> _italic_ and **bold** text, inline `code in backticks`, and [basic links](http://example.com).

Comment: Even though you answered my question earlier, i highly appreciate that you took your time to write another answer with more information + official link. Many thanks Bruno!!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was mistaking single quotes for backticks. The backtick char is the key located to the left of the 1 on your keyboard, it also has the tilde character on it.

` and ~

not the single quote char '